# oracle sql get transactions between the period

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables in oracle sql namely investor, share and transaction.
I am trying to get new investors invested in any shares for a certain period. As they are the new investor, there should not be a transaction in the transaction table for that investor against that share prior to the search period.

For the transaction table with the following records:

```
Id  TranDt                  InvCode ShareCode
1   2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 inv1     S1
2   2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 inv1     S1
3   2020-04-01 00:00:00.000 inv1     S1
4   2021-03-06 11:50:20.560 inv2     S2
5   2020-04-01 00:00:00.000 inv3     S1
```

For the search period between 2020-01-01 and 2020-05-01, I should get the output as

```
5   2020-04-01 00:00:00.000 inv3     S1
```

Though there are transactions for inv1 in the table for that period, there is also a transaction prior to the search period, so that shouldn't be included as it's not considered as new investor within the search period.

Below query is working but it's really taking ages to return the results calling from c# code leading to timeout issues. Is there anything we can do to refine to get the results quicker?

```
WITH 
    INVESTORS AS
    (
         SELECT  I.INVCODE FROM INVESTOR I WHERE I.CLOSED IS NULL)
    ),
    SHARES AS
    (
         SELECT S.SHARECODE FROM SHARE S WHERE S.DORMANT IS NULL))
    ),
    
    SHARES_IN_PERIOD AS 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            T.INVCODE,
            T.SHARECODE,
            T.TYPE
        FROM TRANSACTION T
        JOIN INVESTORS I ON T.INVCODE = I.INVCODE
        JOIN SHARES S ON T.SHARECODE = S.SHARECODE
        WHERE T.TRANDT >= :startDate AND T.TRANDT <= :endDate 
    ),

    PREVIOUS_SHARES AS 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            T.INVCODE,
            T.SHARECODE,
            T.TYPE
        FROM TRANSACTION T
        JOIN INVESTORS I ON T.INVCODE = I.INVCODE
        JOIN SHARES S ON T.TRSTCODE = S.TRSTCODE
        WHERE T.TRANDT < :startDate 
    )

SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
        SP.INVCODE AS InvestorCode,
        SP.SHARECODE AS ShareCode,
        SP.TYPE AS ShareType
FROM SHARES_IN_PERIOD SP
WHERE (SP.INVCODE, SP.SHARECODE, SP.TYPE) NOT IN
    (
        SELECT
            PS.INVCODE,
            PS.SHARECODE,
            PS.TYPE         
        FROM PREVIOUS_SHARES PS
    )
```

With the suggestion given by @Gordon Linoff, I tried following options (for all the shares I need) but they are taking long time too. Transaction table is over 32 million rows.

1.

```
 WITH
  
  SHARES AS
    (
         SELECT S.SHARECODE FROM SHARE S WHERE S.DORMANT IS NULL))
    )


  select t.invcode, t.sharecode, t.type
    from (select t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by invcode, sharecode, type order by trandt) 
    as seqnum
    from transactions t
    ) t
    join shares s on s.sharecode = t.sharecode
    where seqnum = 1 and    
    t.trandt >= date '2020-01-01' and
    t.trandt < date '2020-05-01';
```

2. 

```
WITH 
    INVESTORS AS
    (
         SELECT  I.INVCODE FROM INVESTOR I WHERE I.CLOSED IS NULL)
    ),  
  SHARES AS
    (
         SELECT S.SHARECODE FROM SHARE S WHERE S.DORMANT IS NULL))
    )


  select t.invcode, t.sharecode, t.type
    from (select t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by invcode, sharecode, type order by trandt) 
    as seqnum
    from transactions t
    ) t
    join investors i on i.invcode = t.invcode
    join shares s on s.sharecode = t.sharecode
    where seqnum = 1 and    
    t.trandt >= date '2020-01-01' and
    t.trandt < date '2020-05-01';
```

3. 

```
  select  t.invcode, t.sharecode, t.type
    from (select t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by invcode, sharecode, type order by trandt) 
    as seqnum
    from transactions t
    ) t
    where seqnum = 1 and
    t.sharecode IN (SELECT S.SHARECODE FROM SHARE S WHERE S.DORMANT IS NULL))) 
    and
    t.trandt >= date '2020-01-01' and
    t.trandt < date '2020-05-01';
```

Comment: I assume the date period for your example should be 2021-01-01 to 2021-05-01; otherwise the example doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have just updated the right result. I am looking for first transaction within that period, no transaction for the investor for that share should not happen prior to that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the first record in transactions for a share is during a period, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by invcode, sharecode order by trandt) as seqnum
      from transactions t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and
      t.sharecode = :sharecode and
      t.trandt >= date '2020-01-01' and
      t.trandt < date '2020-05-01';
```

For performance for this code, you want an index on `transactions(invcode, sharecode, trandate)`.

Comment: I have update my post with the queries based on your suggestions for all share codes in 3 ways. But it's still taking quite a long time. Is there anything else I can do?